# Zonal Statistics giving ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, error-000824

I have a script and when I run the **ZonalStatisticsAsTable** I get this error:

- File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 510, in 
  return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
  ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
  ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.
  Failed to execute (ZonalStatisticsAsTable).*

My code is:

```
flist = []
```

````
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root,file)) and file.endswith('.shp'):
            flist.append(os.path.join(root,file))```

    arcpy.env.workspace =r"Z:\EMSV-057_AOIs_Reshape\5_Process\1_TaskA\ModelBuilder\Pruebas_MV\EU_AOI\CAPAS"
    for z in flist:
       shape=z

       erase=arcpy.Erase_analysis(shape,"C:\\OSM_coastlines\\water_polygons.shp", "Tierra", cluster_tolerance="")

       tZONA=arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(erase, "FID", raster, "Tabla", "NODATA", "ALL")
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you either don't have a Spatial Analyst license, or you need to enable it. How to enable extensions is described in the Help page on [Using Extensions in ArcGIS](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/main/guide-books/using-extensions-in-arcgis.htm#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20an%20extension%2C%20select,the%20application%20you%20are%20using.).

You may also have to import and checkout the extension in your code. modified example from the [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/checkoutextension.htm):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

class LicenseError(Exception):
    pass

try:
    if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

    else:
        # raise a custom exception
        raise LicenseError

      #Your main code here using spatial analyst

except LicenseError:
    print("Spatial Analyst license is unavailable")
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
```

Comment: I have active all extensions and when I calculate the statistics in ArcGIS I get its. But I if I run my python.py file I will get the error message

Comment: Thanks for the update - you may need to checkout the extension in your program. See my edits above.